# How stupid am I

Tags: grammaire, constructions, emphase, exclamations

How can I express the meaning of such sentences which start with "How"?

For example,

- "How lucky was I to survive", meaning that I was "so" lucky
- or "How stupid am I", when you criticize yourself and you mean "How much a mankind can be stupid to do such a thing".

Comment: @Random, I think I wasn't really awake when I wrote that. I mixed the sentence with something like "Comment suis-je arrivé ici?". Althought, I often heard "Comment est-ce que je peux être si cave/con/stupide?" which is really similar to "Comme je suis con/cave!". Though, in Québec, we **never** use "comme" as an exclamative word.

Comment: @Sifu ah, ok :)

Answer (score 6):

*Comme / Que je suis stupide !*

*Comme / Que j'ai de la chance d'avoir survécu !*

Informal:

*Qu'est-ce que je suis stupide !*

*Qu'est-ce que j'ai de la chance d'avoir survécu !*

Answer (score 5):

In an informal setting, I assume most French people would say:

> Mais qu'est-ce que je suis con !

Answer (score 2):

In French you could use the following frame:

> Ce que [je suis bête] (alors)!

Answer (score 2):

Shorter than previous answers:

```
Mais quel idiot/abruti/con ! (idiot = neutral, abruti = familiar, con = vulgar)
```

Even shorter:

```
Quel idiot/abruti/con !
```

Even shorter than shorter:

```
L'idiot/L'abruti/Le con !
```

You can replace **idiot** with **imbécile** (neutral).

**Note**: As you are not explicitly saying "I (je)", these sentences can work on other people too.